# defined xml layout in layout-land does not appear in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application according to [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-rss-reader-application-using-sqlite-part-1/). I defined a landscape layout for header.xml in a layout-land folder, but when I change the orientation to landscape, defined layout does not appear in the screen.

Do know Why ?

Thanks

Updated :

Activity Code :

```
public class ACENewsFeedActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Array list for list view
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rssItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    RSSParser rssParser = new RSSParser();

    List<RSSItem> rssItems = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();

    RssFeed rssFeed;

    private static String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static String TAG_LINK = "link";
    private static String TAG_DESRIPTION = "description";
    private static String TAG_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
    //private static String TAG_GUID = "guid"; // not used

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss_item_list);

        /**
         * Calling a backgroung thread will loads recent articles of a website
         * @param rss url of website
         * */
        new loadRSSFeedItems().execute();
       }

       ....
}
```

XMl Layout in landscape mode :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Logo -->

    <!-- Refresh -->


    <!-- Plus Button -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddSite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refreshList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the xml and the activity?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have layouts in both the layout-port and layout-land folders, and the layout-port is showing in portrait orientation but the layout-land is not showing in landscape orientation?

Comment: No I dont have land-port folder, I created layout-land beside layout (default folder) to contain landscape version of header.xml file. Am I Right ?

Comment: check out this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Yes, when you switch to landscape it should check `res/layout-land` for a header.xml and use that if it exists before using the one in `res/layout`. However, if you are putting one in `res/layout-land` you may as well put the other in `res/layout-port` since those are the only two options for screen orientation. This will also definitively prevent the one in `res/layout-port` from being used in landscape orientation (so it may be useful for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Android allows you to provide different versions of resource files to support specific device configurations including screen size/resolution and (as you are trying to do) device orientation. When android is loading a layout file it will look first in the `res/layout-port` folder (if it is in portrait orientation) or in the `res/layout-land` folder (if it is in landscape orientation). If it doesn't find the file it will then look in the regular `res/layout` folder.

Additionally, as noted [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), when certain device configurations change (like device orientation) during runtime android will restart whatever process is currently running by saving the state, destroying it, and then starting it with the saved state info. This allows it to load the layout files again, and it will look it the folder for the new orientation when it tries to load them.

So, if you start your application in portrait it will load the file in `res/layout-port` or `res/layout`. If you then rotate the device to landscape it will destroy your process and restart. However, this time it will be in landscape so it will check `res/layout-land` instead for the layout files.

If you have your files set up this way but it is not operating as you think it should, I'd first verify that it is definitely not using the correct files by putting two different `header.xml` files in the `layout-land` and `layout-port` folders, maybe one with a red background and one with a green background. Make sure to double-check the file references and maybe use Toast to post some debugging info on-screen to ensure that it is inflating layouts properly.

The default behavior is for android to handle the orientation change (which involves destroying your activity and creating a new instance of it which will reload all layout files). This default behavior will always occur unless your activity tag in your manifest file contains the property android:configChanges="orientation". (This tag can take arguments other than orientation - android will handle the config changes for all events except the ones you pass as arguments to this tag.)

If you include the `android:configChanges="orientation"` tag you are telling android NOT to destroy your activity and NOT to reload layout files when the orientation of the device changes. Instead of its default behavior it will call a method (which you define) to allow you to make any changes you wish to make to handle the orientation change yourself rather than letting android handle it automatically. It's intended so that if destroying your activity would be a major inconvenience it doesn't have to be automatically destroyed.

EDIT: added some things from the comment discussion

Comment: I created a layout-port folder and put the header.xml file there, and made some changes to background to make them different, But Just when I start application in portrait (or landscape) mode it shows the difference and when change the orientation to landscape(portrait) it remains the as the same without differences!

Comment: did you also remove the header.xml from the `res/layout` folder?

Comment: The default behavior is for android to handle the orientation change (which involves destroying your activity and creating a new instance of it which will reload all layout files). This default behavior will always occur unless your activity tag in your manifest file contains the property `android:configChanges="orientation"`. I don't know of anything else that can cause the default behavior not to execute on an orientation change. I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: I think you are right, the activity includes "android:configChanges="orientation" as it was in linked example. what is this really for ? But I removed it and saw no difference.

Comment: Did you remove all instance of the `android:configChanges=` tag?

Comment: It is working now, thanks a lot. But if you can please tell me about "android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: If you include that tag you are telling android NOT to destroy your activity and NOT to reload layout files when the orientation of the device changes. Instead it calls a method you provide which will do some other things (whatever you want to do, basically). It's intended so that if you don't want your activity to be destroyed it won't be. Instead it will call a method (which you can define) to allow you to make any changes you wish to make on orientation change yourself rather than letting android handle it automatically.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Comment: Then how to render layout-large and layout-large-land on orientation change without destroying activity?

Answer (score 5):

you should the define `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the `manifest` file for that activity and override the `onConfigChanged()` method in that `setContentView()`

Like so:

```
@Override    
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Here view will created but existing state will gone away. Is it correct?